# MVC Post Cropped Image to Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm using cropit script (https://github.com/scottcheng/cropit) in my Mvc 5 project.
My View:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Crop/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Crop/jquery.cropit.js"></script>
<link href="~/Scripts/Crop/crop.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype =     "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<div class="image-editor" style="margin-left:120px; margin-bottom:25px;">
    <input type="file" name="filex" class="cropit-image-input">
    <div class="cropit-image-preview"></div>
    <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input">
    <input type="hidden" name="image-data" class="hidden-image-data" />
    <button class="export">Export</button>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.image-editor').cropit({

        });

        $('.export').click(function () {
            var imageData = $('.image-editor').cropit('export');
            $('.hidden-image-data').val(imageData);
            //window.open(imageData);
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

When I input an image for example 1000x1000 and send my form with export button, the image is sending to "Img" folder but no cropped. Normally the cropit script demo: http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/

My Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string files)
    {
        var dataurl = Request["image-data"];
        var data = dataurl.Substring(dataurl.IndexOf(",") + 1);
        var newfile = Convert.FromBase64String(data);

        var layoutfilename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_imgage.png";
        var dataFile = Server.MapPath(@"~/A/" + layoutfilename);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(dataFile, newfile);

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: You should submit `imageData` obtained by calling `export` method, to the server rather than the file selected in the fileinput.

Comment: How to submit imageData to server (controller) with jquery or razor?

Comment: Like their [demo](https://github.com/scottcheng/cropit/blob/master/demo/form.html), you'll have to assign it to a hidden field, and convert it bytes[] at the server side. From the code, it seems it exports to base64 or datauri. Identify it first and do the conversion as required.

Comment: Edited code but have null reference error.

Comment: Once you switch from file input to hidden field, you won't able able to accept `HttpPostedFileBase` but rather a `string` containing an exported binary data. What format the plugin is exporting to is up to you to investigate. You'll have to manuall convert the string to byte[] and then save it to file. Conversion depends on the format, if plugin is exporting to base64, a mere call to `Convert.FromBase64String` is enough.